# Integrate BizTalk 2010 with remote SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, integration, adapter, biztalk, biztalk-2010

I would like to configure BizTalk 2010 with a SharePoint Server 2010 that is being run on another machine. This should be possible, but I have found no proper documentation about how to do it. The BizTalk machine is running its own SharePoint and its BizTalk integration works out well. What do I have to install on the remote SharePoint machine to enable the communication?

Microsoft provides instructions for doing this (see [Multiserver deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa547280.aspx)), but they do not answer my question. OK, I have to set the correct user permissions, but how about software?

```
 Machine A                            Machine B
 ----------------------------         ------------------------
| BizTalk 2010               |       | SharePoint Server 2010 |
| SharePoint adapter feature | <---> | ???                    |
 ----------------------------         ------------------------
```

Do I have to:

1. Install the SharePoint Adapter feature on the SharePoint machine

   - This requires BizTalk AFAIK
2. Configure the adapter feature on the BizTalk server to use the remote SharePoint site
3. Do something else

Of course, I could use the SOAP adapter but that would be a lot of work.